# CSRF and SPA - how to secure cookies

Tags: reactjs, csrf, samesite

CSRF & SPA
Hi,

I am currently trying to solve if CSRF is a problem for my SPA.

I have a ReactJS frontend application which communicates with my Spring boot backend. On successful login, two cookies are stored:

1. accessToken - sameSite(strict), httpOnly(true), secured(true), path=/
2. refreshToken - sameSite(strict), httpOnly(true), secured(true), path=/auth/refreshToken

As definition says. I am sending accessToken to all secured endpoints and refreshToken only to refresh token endpoint. All communication is done by axios with withCredentials=true to all secured endpoints.

Backend only allows one origin (CORS) from frontend, frontend runs on nginx and because I use react-router-dom, I have to use some additional configuration for nginx

```
location / {
try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

My backend also uses swagger UI to call some endpoints directly without frontend. Here are my results:

1. If I log in in frontend, I am automatically authenticated in swagger-ui and vice versa.
2. If I click on frontend link (for example from my email message where is the link to frontend), it redirects me to my frontend page a viola, I am still authenticated if the access tokens in cookies have not expired.

Now, my security guy tells me that I am not CSRF protected. I must confess that I do not know much about CSRF and I thought that sameSite(string) will handle this just fine without me changing anything.

So basically, it means that if there is a link on any other site to my frontend and you have been previously authenticated with my frontend, the frontend opens just fine. This testing happens of course on the same computer.

So, is this really CSRF breach? If it is, why sameSite(strict) does not handles this and is someone here please who would very simply describe the CSRF? I know how it works on sever side rendering when server send you a form with token and when you send a form with that token, server verifies that token and it works but in SPA where there is only stateless behaviour, I really dont know.

Thank you

Any help appreciated